# Pivot DataFrame with DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data, which I've faked using:

```
def fake_disrete_data():
    in_li = []
    sample_points = 24 * 4

    for day, bias in zip((11, 12, 13), (.5, .7, 1.)):
        day_time = datetime(2016, 6, day, 0, 0, 0)
        for x in range(int(sample_points)):

            in_li.append((day_time + timedelta(minutes=15*x),
                          int(x / 4),
                          bias))

    return pd.DataFrame(in_li, columns=("time", "mag_sig", "bias")).set_index("time")

fake_disc = fake_disrete_data()
```

I can pivot each column individually using and then concatenate them using:

```
cols = list(fake_disc.columns.values)
dfs = []
for col in cols:
    dfs.append(pd.pivot_table(fake_disc,
                              index=fake_disc.index.date,
                              columns=fake_disc.index.hour,
                              values=col,
                              aggfunc=np.mean))

all_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=cols)
```

But is there a better way to do this?

I'm trying to follow the answers seen in [Pandas pivot table for multiple columns at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165629/pandas-pivot-table-for-multiple-columns-at-once) and [How to pivot multilabel table in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971114/how-to-pivot-multilabel-table-in-pandas), but I'm having a difficult time translating their methods to the `DateTimeIndex` case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Review

all in all, this code is rather clean. I would use a generator comprehension and `itertools.chain` in `fake_disrete_data` instead of the nested for-loop, but that is a matter of taste

### linewraps

I prefer to wrap lines after the `(` instead of the first argument. Here I follow the same rules as [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style.html#how-black-wraps-lines). This leads to lesser indents, but slightly longer code, for example:

```
dfs.append(
    pd.pivot_table(
        fake_disc,
        index=fake_disc.index.date,
        columns=fake_disc.index.hour,
        values=col,
        aggfunc=np.mean,
    )
)
```

### list comprehension

instead of the appending, you can do

```
dfs = [
    pd.pivot_table(
        fake_disc,
        index=fake_disc.index.date,
        columns=fake_disc.index.hour,
        values=col,
        aggfunc=np.mean,
    )
    for col in columns
]
```

or even better, feed a dict to `pd.concat`, so you don't have to specify the `keys` argument

```
dfs = {
    col: pd.pivot_table(
        fake_disc,
        index=fake_disc.index.date,
        columns=fake_disc.index.hour,
        values=col,
        aggfunc='mean',
    )
    for col in fake_disc.columns
}
pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

I also changed the `np.mean` to `'mean'`, so you don't have to specifically import np for this, and avoided having to create the `columns` list

## Alternative approach

`pd.pivot` is a wrapper around `unstack`, `groupby` and `stack`. If you want to do something more complicated, you can do those operations by hand

```
fake_disc = fake_disrete_data()
fake_disc.columns = fake_disc.columns.set_names('variable')
df = fake_disc.stack().to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'value'})
df['hour'] = df.index.get_level_values('time').hour
```

this creates an intermediary `DataFrame`

```
time                variable    value   hour
2016-06-11 00:00:00 mag_sig     0.0     0
2016-06-11 00:00:00 bias        0.5     0
2016-06-11 00:15:00 mag_sig     0.0     0
2016-06-11 00:15:00 bias        0.5     0
2016-06-11 00:30:00 mag_sig     0.0     0
...
```

This you can group. To group the time per hour, you can use `pd.Grouper`

```
pivot = (
    df.groupby([pd.Grouper(level="time", freq="d"), "hour", "variable"])
    .mean()
    .unstack(["variable", "hour"])
    .sort_index(axis="columns", level=["variable", "hour"])
)
```

> ```
>   value
> variable  bias    ...     mag_sig
> hour  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ...     14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
> time                                                                                  
> 2016-06-11    0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     0.5     ...     14.0    15.0    16.0    17.0    18.0    19.0    20.0    21.0    22.0    23.0
> 2016-06-12    0.7     0.7     0.7     0.7     0.7     0.7     0.7     0.7     0.7     0.7     ...     14.0    15.0    16.0    17.0    18.0    19.0    20.0    21.0    22.0    23.0
> 2016-06-13    1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     ...     14.0    15.0    16.0    17.0    18.0    19.0    20.0    21.0    22.0    23.0
> ```

### performance

according to the `%%timeit` cell magic in Jupyterlab,
the first approach (with the dict and concat) takes about 23ms, the second approach about 10ms. Depending on your usecase, this difference might be important. If it is not, pick the method which is most readable to your future self